# Symfony How to remove constraint from default validation group

Tags: php, validation, symfony, symfony-forms

I have form type with some data from entity.

There is a field that is required and it's is not in the form type.

This is the default validation constraint :

```
public static function loadValidatorMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata)
    {
        $name_blank     = new NotBlank();
        $name_blank->message    = "The name should not be blank";
        $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('name', $name_blank);

    }
```

Is there a way to override Symfony default validation?

```
public function checkRequiredDynamicFields(ExecutionContextInterface $context) {

$metadata = $context->getMetadata();

if (empty($this->name)) {
    $context->buildViolation('This is a required field.')
        ->atPath('name')
        ->addViolation();
    $context->buildViolation("Missing the title for conference section.")->addViolation();
}


}
```

Comment: Can you provide your Entity and your FormType ?

Comment: The question is not clear, however you take a look at this http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html#the-callback-method to validate custom behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building the Form, consider adding `'mapped' => false` to the extra field:

```
$qb->add('unbound_field', null, array('mapped' => false))
```

If you want to add a custom validation afterward, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995440/how-to-add-validation-to-unbound-form-field-in-symfony2)

Comment: I don't think this what he is looking for. What I understand so far is he has some validation contraint on a property of an entity.
Those property does not appear on the formType and the constraint is triggered when he want to check the form is valid

Comment: @Stevan, can you reformulate your question to erase confusion, Olivier have a good point.